# Clear dropzone.js thumbnail image after uploading an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, dropzone.js

I have using dropzone.js in mvc by following this [tutorial](http://venkatbaggu.com/file-upload-in-asp-net-mvc-using-dropzone-js-and-html5/) for uploading images but after uploading the image the thumbnail image still showing and I need it to be removed after every time I upload an image.

I have tried to replace the generated HTML after uploading the image using jQuery but it not showing correctly as the first time I need to refresh the page to show correctly but I don't want to do that.

```
 $("#ImageUpload").replaceWith('<form action="/Products/SaveUploadedFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="dropzoneForm">'
 +'<div class="fallback">'
 +'<input name="file" type="file" multiple />'
 +'<input type="submit" value="Upload" />'
 +'</div>');
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can try this:

```
myDropzone.on("complete", function(file) {
  myDropzone.removeFile(file);
});
```

More information here:
http://www.dropzonejs.com/#dropzone-methods

Comment: `removeFile()`/`removeAllFiles()` delete uploaded files from the server-side too, which is not what the topic starter is asking for.

Comment: @MikeB.: Are you sure? The docs says _"If you want to remove an added file from the **dropzone**, you can call `.removeFile(file)`."_ From what I understand it only affects the **dropzone**. The method triggers the `removedfile` event which _"you can listen to... and delete the file from your server **if you want to**."_ Deleting the file from the server seems to be **optional**. Correct me if I'm worng...

Comment: I not sure for 100%, but I experienced the phenomenon when `removeFile()` removed it from the server as well out-of-box (I didn't cared about `removefile` event particularly) and than I saw it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43683894/462347 . So, perhaps, this point worth additional attention.

Comment: If you have "addRemoveLinks" enabled and dropzone-removed-file callback to remove the uploaded file from server using an api call, then calling removeFile()/removeAllFiles() will make the API call and will delete files from server as well. In such scenarios, (When you dont want the delete API call to happen ) use   http://stackoverflow.com/a/43683894/462347

Comment: it user selects multiple file it'll not work, right?

Answer (score 15):

`removeAllFiles()` and `removeFile()` will trigger the server-side removal too, if you hooked Dropzone to remove files as well.

The solution to clear it only client-side, remove the file preview, and if you had a blank state message, remove the `dz-started` class to prevent the Dropzone CSS from hiding it:

```
$('.dropzone')[0].dropzone.files.forEach(function(file) { 
  file.previewElement.remove(); 
});

$('.dropzone').removeClass('dz-started');
```

Comment: can you tell me where to add this? I am new to flask

Answer (score 8):

Another option (similar to answer of Giraldi, but then when all files are completed):

```
myDropzone.on("queuecomplete", function () {
    this.removeAllFiles();
});
```

Comment: It will delete uploaded files from the server-side too, while the TS asks how to clear the dropzone file field (from thumbnails), and not how to remove already uploaded file.

Answer (score 5):

it was actually an easy thing to do but some time it go hard so i just delete the dropzone generated code using jquery and add a button with `'id = btnCreate'` then

```
 $('#btnCreate').click(function () {
        $('div.dz-success').remove();
   });
```

and when i upload the thumbnail image removed after i click the button

Comment: Sorry but this is a terrible solution. The other two answers using the provided removeFile() and removeAllFiles() methods are correct and will cause less headaches down the road. The internal file counter will not reset when doing this.

Answer (score 3):

Just an fyi...

The method `removeAllFiles` is not necessarily the prime choice.  Which is the same as `removeFile(file)`.

I have an event handler for dropZone's `removedfile` event...  I'm using it to send a server message to delete the respective file from the server (should a user delete the thumbnail after it's been uploaded).  Using the method `removeAllFiles` (as well as the individualized `removeFile(file))` fires the event `removedfile` which deletes the uploaded images in addition to clearing the thumbnails.

So one could add some finessing around this but in the reality of it the method as mentioned in the primary answer on this thread is not correct.

Looking through the api for Dropzone I am not seeing an API call to simply reset or clear the thumbnails...  The method `disable()` will clear the stored file names and what not but does not clear the thumbnails...  Seems dropzoneJS is actually missing a critical API call to be honest.

My work around is to manually reset the containing div for dropzone:

```
document.getElementById("divNameWhereDropzoneClassIs").innerHTML = ""
```

This clears the thumbnails without firing off the event `removedfile` which is supposed to be used for deleting an image from the server...

Answer (score 3):

It is very simple if you listen complete event in your dropzone options:

```
const dropZoneOptions = {
        url: ...,
        // complete event
        complete: function(file) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.removeFile(file); // right here after 3 seconds you can clear
          }, 3000);
        },
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
docsDropzone.on('complete', function (response)
{
   $(".dz-preview").remove();
});
```

Above works for me

Answer (score 1):

try this on your library dropzone dropzone.js; but set time out to auto close 2500

```
success: function(file) {
  if (file.previewElement) {
    return file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success"),
    $(function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.dz-success').fadeOut('slow');
      },2500);
    });
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of clear those thumbnails

```
Dropzone.prototype.removeThumbnail = function () {
    $(".dz-preview").fadeOut('slow');
    $(".dz-preview:hidden").remove();
};
```

then you call it like this:

```
{your_dropzone}.removeThumbnail();
```